# Atom not recognizing installed module in VirtualENV

Tags: python, selenium, virtualenv

I have been working on trying to find a resolution for this all day.  I created a virtualENV running python3.  I wrote 3 lines of simple code and my output is saying:

```
"Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/josh.frazier/Desktop/magnolia/env/test.py", line 1, in <module> from selenium import webdriver
ImportError: No module named selenium
[Finished in 0.043s]"
```

The problem is that selenium is installed.  I used pip3 after activating the environment.

code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get('http://google.com')
```

[image: terminal-Pip Freeze]

[image: browser]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If, from your terminal where you have activated the virtual environment, you run `python test.py`, what happens?

My guess is that your IDE is using your system installation of Python (and its packages) and not your virtual environment's Python and packages.

Comment: Interesting.  It actually brought up Google in Firefox.  I wish I could add a relieved emoji here.  Now I have to figure out out to get it to change my ide settings.